# How to use a for loop to calculate the row means of a Matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix (X), in which I am trying to calculate the mean of each row. I know that rowMeans() can be used and will work just fine, however, I am trying to prove that a for loop can be used as well. How would I accomplish this?

```
X <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 25, ncol = 4)
for (i in 1:n) {
  nums[i] <- mean(X)
}
print(nums[i])
```

[1] 50.5

**VS.**

```
rowMeans(X)
```

> ```
> [1] 38.5 39.5 40.5 41.5 42.5 43.5 44.5 45.5 46.5 47.5 48.5 49.5 50.5 51.5 52.5 53.5 54.5 55.5 56.5 57.5 58.5 59.5 60.5 61.5 62.5
> ```

Comment: `apply(X, 1, mean)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! What does the 1 represent within the apply function?

Comment: In each iteration you are running the mean of the whole matrix. Should be `mean(X[i,]` probably, instead of just `mean(X)`

Comment: `1` means *do the operation rowwise*.

Comment: To perform mean(X[i,]), is there anything else that I should be doing for it to run?```{r}
X <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 25, ncol = 4)
for (i in 1:n) {
  Xmean <- mean(X[i, ])
}
Xmean
```      I get an out of bounds error when performed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turning @David's comment into an answer.

```r
row_m <- vector("list", nrow(X))
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
  row_m[i]<- mean(X[i,])
}

unlist(row_m)

#  [1] 38.5 39.5 40.5 41.5 42.5 43.5 44.5 45.5 46.5 47.5 48.5 49.5 50.5 51.5
# [15] 52.5 53.5 54.5 55.5 56.5 57.5 58.5 59.5 60.5 61.5 62.5
```

Comment: If you'd do `row_m <- c()` you won't have to `unlist`after.

Comment: `row_m` is initialized as a `list` at the beginning not?

Comment: I you _would_ do I meant ;)

Comment: Yap, that would be unlist-ing the not list :)